# How to reuse ingress routing rules for inter-service communication within a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I have various microservices running inside a kubernetes cluster. And I have a client library that provides methods to interact with these different microservices. The client library can be installed in the microservices to talk to other microservices running within the cluster.

The client library internally calls other microservices using REST endpoints.
The interface of the client library is such that it only takes a single hostname parameter and makes HTTP calls to different endpoints on that hostname to talk to different microservices. In order for this to be possible we need a proxy that would provide path based routing.

I also have various ingresses (nginx-ingress) defined in my cluster that expose these microservices outside the cluster using HTTPS and provides path based routing.

Now, I want to be able to reuse the existing ingress routing capability to allow microservices to talk to each other through this client library.

But the problem is that I don't want to reach out to the external URL that the ingress listens on because:

1. I don't want to go out to the internet to hit the microservices already running within the cluster.
2. I also don't want to do TLS validation because it is a within-cluster communication only.

However, I also don't want to create a special proxy service for this and replicate the routing rules there when I already have those rules defined in the ingress yaml files.

Is there a way we can reuse the ingress's existing routing capability to provide path based routing for inter-service communication under a single hostname/service name that is only reachable from within the cluster and which does not need TLS verification (work with HTTP)?

Comment: I didn't fully get the picture: is my understanding correct that you'd like to have a (more or less) exact clone of your public ingress that is available just internally?
In this case, can you just have another ingress-controller installation, without ssl, that mounts the very same ingress as the public one with different ingress class and domain, but reached via its proper service that should already be available within the cluster once the "internal" ingress controller is installed and configured?

Answer (score 0):

You could label your backend microservices with a specific label and then create a `Service` that would *select* those pods using the same label. **But** you won’t be able to map specific ports to specific pods and most likely the application level routing would fail.

That being said, you will need to look at [Service Mesh](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/microservices/what-is-a-service-mesh) solutions like [istio](https://istio.io/), [linkerd](https://linkerd.io/), [traefik](https://traefik.io/) to handle this use case appropriately.